# centering a position fixed three column layout

Tags: html, css

I have

```
----------------------------------------------------
|                                                  |
|  |-------------------------------------------|   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |  15%   |   |
|  |   15%   |         70%            |  fixed |   |
|  |  fixed  |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  |         |                        |        |   |
|  | ------------------------------------------|   |
|        max width of the this 100% is 400px       |
=====================================================
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/

What I am not able to achieve is the max width of the entire three columns as 400px; and centering the three columns.

How do i achieve this.

Comment: Simplest way is http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/6/ - specifying heights of the containers - however, you'll need to play with the font-size and/or widths.

Comment: @dash I have edited the question check it now

Comment: You need to put them inside a container and set the width of that. If they are floated within this container (see the #container class in the jsfiddle, which is also floated) then they are filling the width. However, is it the fact that the content is bleeding out that is worrying you? You need to lower the font-size to stop that from happening, or set overflow:none;

Comment: http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/fixed.htm you mean you want to achieve something like this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/8/ - this modifies the container to use absolute positioning. Note the margin left has to be half the width. This works from IE6 onwards if that's important, too.

Comment: @umutto No, OP wants it window wide, but with a maximum of 400 pixels and the side columns must be fixed to the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with CSS2, see [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/fwQq4/10/):

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Style sheet:

```
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#left {
    width: 15%;
    background: red;
}
#middle{
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    background: yellow;
}
#right {
    width: 15%;
    margin-left: 85%;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: the layout will break if there is not enough content on the div#right.

Comment: Good catch! Updated the answer and fiddle.

Comment: awesome, too good! any pointers as to where i can learn good CSS for these kind of stuff

Comment: [WestCIV CSS Guide](http://westciv.com/wiki/CSS_Guide) is where I learned the basics. Everything next I learned by using common sense, and if I now want some extra specific information, I use [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp). (And I will propably be shot right now).

Comment: PAN! :) Specific information: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html + http://instacss.com + http://caniuse.com (CSS3) + http://reference.sitepoint.com/css + MDN (and Opera OWSC http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/ for "courses"?)

Comment: @NGLN another problem arises with this method :-) The wrapper element stays on top of the middle element and prevents all the clicks events on it. Please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/16/

Comment: If the sections may be changed in order, then use [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/17/). Otherwise, try to _activate/focus_ (don't know how) the middle section, because when you click the link in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/18/), it works again.

Comment: @NGLN I use google chrome and I am still not able to click it

Comment: @NGLN The wrappers are on top of the middle element. So when i click its on the wrapper, what can I do to bring the wrapper on top. Check this out!

Comment: @NGLN setting position:relative and z-index:1 solves the issue. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471770/unable-to-click-a-div-how-do-i-bring-one-div-on-top-of-another    Thank you so much for your help and time.. Really appreciate it

Comment: @SAnandNarayan Nice. Glad I could be of assistance.