# Unable to click a div, how do I bring one div on top of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fwQq4/19/

Here I have the wrapper class (`div.wrapper`) above the `div#middle`. So if I click on the `div#middle` the click is happening on `div.wrapper`. How can I get the click to have `middleElement` as the source.

The real problem is I have many items inside the middle element, and I want to find which element the user clicked on.

How can I get the middle element on top!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these two lines of css to `#middle`:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: ahh!! last time i tried the z-index:1 without position:relative ... That didnt work.. Now this works...    What does specifiy position:relative have to do with z-index:1

Comment: When you set `position` to anything but `static` you remove the element from the regular content flow of the page and take control of the positioning. `z-index` won't have any effect if the element isn't removed from the reqular flow.

Comment: but position relative will not remove the content from the normal flow right? i thought only position absolute and fixed remove them from the flow

Comment: W3 docs: [relative positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning) and [z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)